# PHP Script not always executing

Tags: php, html, css

I seem to be having problems with a PHP script which seems to have some intermittent problems.

Im hoping you can help. The php script is simply used to provide users with different stylesheets dependant on their HTTP agent. (I know this is not responsive mobile design)

This work is for a corporate project therefore unfortunately I cant share any links...

The problem I seem to be having is often this script fails to execute and the user is not directed to appropriate stylesheet. This can be simulated by visiting the page and hitting refresh... When the error occurs and I directly visit the PHP script I am simply provided with the code snippet. When the script is working and I do the same I am directed straight to the appropriate CSS file as expected.

Why could this be? Is this a server side problem or is there something wrong with my implementation?

```
<?php

    // MOBILE
    $blackberry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BB10");
    $blackberry2 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $chrome = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome");
    $safari = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Safari");

    // REDIRECTS 
    // MOBILE
    if ($blackberry == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: style.css');
    }
    else if ($blackberry2 == true)
    {
    header('Location: bb7.css');
    }
    else if ($iphone == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: style.css');
    }
    else if ($ipad == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: ipad.css');
    }
    else if ($chrome == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: style.css');
    }
    else if ($safari == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: style.css');
    }
?>
```

HTML Code...

```
<!--Dynamic CSS Scripts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php">
<!--END-->
```

Thanks!

Comment: Loose comparison; what happens if "BB10" appears as the very first characters of the USER AGENT string, and strpos will be 0, which equates to FALSE, not to TRUE.... change all your if statements to the equivalent of `$blackberry !== false`

Comment: step1 : try to get the value of USER_AGENT and see if its coming properlty. Step2 : add an exit() after each header()

Comment: PHP is not CSS . You should include the CSS instead.

Comment: Always use absolute path in header.

Comment: NB: Using User Agent sniffing, especially for style sheets is very unreliable. Don't do it. There are hardly any bugs in browsers any more that require separate style sheets and CSS has features (like media queries) that allow for different displays depending on the abilities of the browsers.

Comment: Ok thanks all....

I have attempted the upload of the scripts onto a personal server and don't have the same issues. 

If this was to be a PHP config issue on the corporate server, what could it be?